# Syntax error when i run homestead up in my console

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

When I run `homestead up` on my console I get a syntax error like this:

```
 There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
 message is reproduced below for convenience:

 C:/Users/Evan Oscar/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:6: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
 ..."C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\homestead...
 ...                               ^
 C:/Users/Evan Oscar/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:7: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
 ...criptPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\Evan Oscar\.h...
 ...                               ^
```

Can someone please tell me what is causing the syntax error?
I think its the `PATH` of my `homestead.yaml` folder that's causing the problem?

Here is the `PATH` from my Vagrantfile:

```
homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\aliases")
```

Comment: Remove tag from title; improve English; improve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather not have `Evan Oscar` in double quotes inside your path.

You should have here:

```
homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\Evan Oscar\.homestead\.vagrant\homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\Evan Oscar\.homestead\.vagrant\after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\Evan Oscar\.homestead\.vagrant\aliases")
```

and not

```
homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("C:\cygwin64\home\"Evan Oscar"\.homestead\.vagrant\aliases")
```

Comment: thank you
but now its said `C:/Users/Evan Oscar/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:17:in `read`: Invalid argument'